# How to conditionally conform to delegate protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

If I am including frameworks in my iOS project that are only available in (for example) iOS 9, but I am still supporting iOS 8, how do I conditionally conform to a delegate protocol depending on the iOS version? For example, I understand I can include the framework conditionally like this:

```
#import <Availability.h>
#ifdef __IPHONE_9_0
#import <Something/Something.h>
#endif
```

But what if that framework also needs to conform to a delegate protocol?

`@interface ExampleController () <UITextViewDelegate, SomethingDelegate>`

How do I only include "SomethingDelegate" if I'm on iOS 9?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in roughly the same manner:

```
@interface ExampleController () <UITextViewDelegate
#ifdef __IPHONE_9_0
     , SomethingDelegate
#endif
>
```

By the way, this is *not* the way you should check if the device is running iOS 9 - [this only checks if your Xcode supports iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301751/ifdef-iphone-8-0-code-runs-also-on-ios-7).

Comment: Oh my, I've been mislead. Thank you! I will accept as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Glorfindel is more clean, and I would support it, but just to have an alternative answer.

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_9_0
    #import <Something/Something.h>
    #define DELEGATES UITextViewDelegate, SomethingDelegate
#else
    #define DELEGATES UITextViewDelegate
#endif

@interface ExampleController : UIViewController <DELEGATES>
```

And there is also a question, what are you going to do with methods belonging to `SomethingDelegate` protocol, also `#ifdef/#endif` or just keep them "as is", as they never be called.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good task for a category, with its own files. The contents of those files can be entirely `ifdef`d out.

```
//ExampleController+SomethingDelegate.h
#ifdef __IPHONE_9_0

#import <Something/Something.h>

@interface ExampleController (SomethingDelegate) <SomethingDelegate>
@end
#endif
```

---

```
//ExampleController+SomethingDelegate.m
#import "ExampleController+SomethingDelegate.h"

#ifdef __IPHONE_9_0

@implementation ExampleController (SomethingDelegate) <SomethingDelegate>

 - (BOOL)somethingShouldMakePancakes:(Something *)something;    

@end

#endif
```

This reads much better than splitting the declaration across multiple lines with a macro in the middle, and keeps all the relevant methods in one place, under one `ifdef`.